# Number Theory: Prove that $7^{7^n}+1$ can be shown as product of at least $2n+3$ prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for each natural number $n$, $7^{7^n}+1$ can be represented as product of at least $2n+3$ prime numbers. (Prime numbers are not necessarily different)

Any hints how to start the proof?

Comment: Note that $7^{7^n}+1\equiv (-1)^{7^n}+1\equiv 0\mod 8$, I suspect that's where the $+3$ comes from

Comment: Maybe using [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization)

Comment: Hint: $(x+1)\mid (x^7+1)$. Consider (a) factoring the quotient, and (b) showing that the GCD of those terms with previous values is small.

Comment: This can be done with the following factorisation:

$$\frac{7^{7^{n+1}}+1}{7^{7^n}+1} = (7^{7^n})^6-(7^{7^n})^5+(7^{7^n})^4-(7^{7^n})^3+(7^{7^n})^2-(7^{7^n})+1$$ You now have to prove that the latter is not a prime.

Comment: This problem was proposed in USAMO 2008. You can check AoPS for solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization) gives
$$7^{14k+7} + 1 = (7^{2k+1}+1)\cdot(C-D)(C+D)$$

with $$C,D=(7^{6k+3} + 3\cdot 7^{4k+2} + 3\cdot 7^{2k+1} + 1),(7^{5k + 3} + 7^{3k+2} + 7^{k+1})$$

so for $14k+7=7^{n+1}$:

$$\begin{align*}7^{7^{n+1}} + 1 \;= &\;\;(7^{7^n}+1)\\
&\cdot\left[(7^{3\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{2\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{7^n} + 1)+(7^{(5\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(3\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(7^n+1)/2})\right]\\
&\cdot\left[(7^{3\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{2\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{7^n} + 1)-(7^{(5\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(3\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(7^n+1)/2})\right]\end{align*}$$

For $n=0$ this gives $$7^{7^1}+1=2^3\cdot \text{ two factors}$$
So by induction $7^{7^n}+1$ is a product at least $2n+3$ factors $>1$.