# Prove that $\frac {7^{7^{2024}} +1}{7^{7^{2023}} +1}$ is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\frac {7^{7^{2024}} +1}{7^{7^{2023}} +1}$ is composite

My steps were to transform $7^{7^{2024}} = 7^{7^{2023}\times 7}$ and substitute $x = 7^{7^{2023}}$ to get
$$\frac {x^7+1}{x+1}=  x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$$ The problem can probably be solved in a typical NT way, but the lecturer who gave us the problem suggested an algebraic approach, so to try find factors of an expression therefore disproving it being prime.

Comment: We have no algebraic factors , so I guess we can proof a quite small number to divide this monster , but no idea yet which and why.

Comment: For what it's worth, replacing $n=2024$ with  very small values gives a sequence of composites but no obvious factors. With $n=3$, for instance, the least prime factor is $32442313$.

Comment: At least there is no prime $p$ below $10^9$ that divides the numerator and doesn't divide the denominator (though this doesn't yet fully exclude that such prime may divide the quotient)

Comment: Follows immediately by the Aurifeuillian factorization [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345950/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall the following well-known identity :

$$(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7=7ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)^2$$

Note that, this is not a new finding . Recall IMO 1984, Problem $2$ .

This identity leads to :

$$\small{\begin{align}\frac{x^7+1}{x+1}=(x+1)^6-7x(x^2+x+1)^2\end{align}}$$

Thus, we reduced the problem to $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ .

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [this question and its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256547/number-theory-prove-that-77n1-can-be-shown-as-product-of-at-least-2n3?noredirect=1), the following identity can be found there which is verifiable :
$$\begin{align*}7^{7^{n+1}} + 1 \;= &\;\;(7^{7^n}+1)\\
&\times\left[(7^{3\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{2\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{7^n} + 1)+(7^{(5\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(3\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(7^n+1)/2})\right]\\
&\times\left[(7^{3\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{2\cdot7^n} + 3\cdot 7^{7^n} + 1)-(7^{(5\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(3\cdot7^n+1)/2} + 7^{(7^n+1)/2})\right],\end{align*}$$

which instantly shows that $\frac{7^{7^{n+1}}+1}{7^{7^n}+1}$ has two factors. One sees that the second factor is the smaller one, and is greater than $1$ for all $n\geq 1$ by comparing appropriate terms of the addend bracket and subtrahend bracket.

Thus, for $n=2023$ the given quantity is composite.

This kind of factorization arises from the more general identity
\begin{align}
7^{14k+7} + 1 &= (7^{2k+1}+1)\\
&\times (7^{6k+3} + 3\cdot 7^{4k+2} + 3\cdot 7^{2k+1} + 1) \\
& \times (7^{5k + 3} + 7^{3k+2} + 7^{k+1}).
\end{align}

To see how that identity is derived, one needs to note that the identity above belongs to a special class of factorization identities known as [Aurifeuillian factorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization). To spot our factorization, one needs to look at the case $b=7$ in the page provided.

---

Expanding further on these kinds of factorizations requires us to define the [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $$
\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{k=1,\gcd(k,n)=1}^n (x-e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}),
$$
For example, if $p$ is a prime, then a standard manipulation yields that $$\Phi_p(x) = 1+x+\ldots+x^{p-1}.$$
In your case, what might be more important to observe is that if $n = 2p$ where $p$ is a prime, then $$
\Phi_p(x) = 1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots + x^{p-1}.
$$
Match this to the expression you got when $p=7$. The polynomial $x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ is nothing but $\Phi_{14}(x)$. If you need help spotting cyclotomic polynomials, at least some cases may be possible to spot, as suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Easy_cases_for_computation).

Aurifeuillian factorizations *begin with the observation* that you're factorizing a number of the form $\Phi_{n}(k)$ where $n,k$ is an integer. As you can see, the number you're trying to factorize is precisely of that form, where $n = 14$ and $k = 7^{7^{2023}}$.

Once this is done, then one can look at Schinzel's landmark paper.

*Schinzel, Andrzej*, [**On primitive prime factors of (a^ n -b^ n)**](https://oeis.org/A195166), Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 58, 555-562 (1962). [ZBL0114.02605](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0114.02605).

I won't state Schinzel's main result in his language, but instead defer to the following article :

*Granville, Andrew; Pleasants, Peter*, [**Aurifeuillian factorization**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-05-01766-7), Math. Comput. 75, No. 253, 497-508 (2006). [ZBL1107.11050](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1107.11050).

which gives the following statement :

> Suppose that $n$ is a composite number not divisible by $8$ and let $N$ be the largest odd factor of $n$ (note that $n=N,2N,4N$ are the only possibilities now). Suppose that $d$ is any squarefree divisor of $N$ (which can be negative if $n=4N$). There exist polynomials $U_{n,d},V_{n,d}$ with integer coefficients such that $$
> \Phi_N(x) = U_{N,d}(x)^2 - d(-1)^{(d-1)/2}xV_{N,d}(x)^2, \\
> \Phi_{2N}(x) = U_{2N,d}(x)^2 + d(-1)^{(d-1)/2}xV_{2N,d}(x)^2, \\
> \Phi_{4N}(x) = U_{4N,d}(x)^2 -2dxV_{4N,d}(x)^2.
> $$

Let's try this with the illustrative example given by the same paper. Suppose that you take $x = ay^2$ where $a = d(-1)^{(d-1)/2}$ in the first example above. Then, you get :$$
\Phi_N(x) = U_{N,d}(ay^2)^2 - d(-1)^{(d-1)/2}(ay^2)V_{N,d}(ay^2)^2 \\
= (U_{N,d}(ay^2))^2 - (ad(-1)^{(d-1)/2}yV_{N,d}(ay^2))^2 \\
= (U_{N,d}(ay^2) + ad(-1)^{(d-1)/2}yV_{N,d}(ay^2))  \times (U_{N,d}(ay^2) - ad(-1)^{(d-1)/2}yV_{N,d}(ay^2)).
$$
From a cursory reading it is not clear if the polynomials can be constructed using the proof or not. Nevertheless, the Wikipedia page on Aurifeuillian factorizations is a decent enough start for any olympiad type problems.

Some degree comparison constraints will tell you that for large enough values of $a,y$, the above factors are both greater than $1$. In other words, $\Phi_N(ay^2)$ is composite for all choices of $y$ and $a = d(-1)^{(d-1)/2}$ where $d$ is any square-free factor of $N$, as long as $n$ is large enough (I am not sure if the factorization is nontrivial for all $n \geq 1$).

Similar results show that $\Phi_{2N}(d(-1)^{\frac{d+1}{2}}y^2)$ and $\Phi_{2N}(2d)$ are also composite for large enough $N$, where $d$ is any square free factor of $N$ and $y$ is arbitrary.

Thus, we obtain a larger class of numbers that can be shown to be composite using the abstract method of Schinzel. This includes the number in question, which is $\Phi_{14}(7^{7^{2023}})$ using the decomposition $$
\Phi_{14}(7^{7^{2023}}) = \Phi_{2 \times 7} \left(7 \times (-1)^{(7+1)/2} \times \left(7^{\frac{7^{2023}-1}{2}}\right)^2\right)
$$
and matching this up with the decomposition I gave earlier.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)

Comment: (+1) There are not 10's but 100's of dupes on this site, which are not deleted but are not abstract but exact copies of each other.I have a hard time understanding the deletion of the answer that put so much effort into. Presumably the votes are CURED votes (most likely) I would appreciate it if you could briefly answer these 3 questions: If the question is deleted, do I have enough reputation to undo the deletion? 2)Since I have already voted, I cannot vote again. So does this result in not being able to vote for undelete? 3)How can 3 people use delete vote such a highly voted 7+7+4 question?

Comment: @lonestudent The best thing to do in cases like this is to move the answer into one of the dupes (assuming it has novel content).  Unfortunately the gamified nature of the platform discourages such (since rep is not moved too) even though it is much healthier for the site.